# How does Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide() work internally?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

based on this article: https://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx
we know that volatile doesn’t prevent a write followed by a read from being swapped, and this can create brainteasers:

```
class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile
{
  volatile int x, y;
 
  void Test1()        // Executed on one thread
  {
    x = 1;            // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int a = y;        // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
    ...
  }
 
  void Test2()        // Executed on another thread
  {
    y = 1;            // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int b = x;        // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
    ...
  }
}
```

it's possible for a and b to both end up with a value of 0 (despite the use of volatile on both x and y):

based on this article:
https://onurgumus.github.io/2021/02/07/Demystifying-the-volatile-keyword.html

we can fix the example as

**Solution One**:

```
class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile
{
  volatile int x, y;
 
  void Test1()        // Executed on one thread
  {
    x = 1;            
    Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
    int a = y;        
    ...
  }
 
  void Test2()        // Executed on another thread
  {
    y = 1; 
    Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();          
    int b = x;
    ...
  }
}
```

**Solution Two**:

```
class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile
{
  volatile int x, y;
 
  void Test1()        // Executed on one thread
  {
    x = 1;            
    Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide();
    int a = y;        
    ...
  }
 
  void Test2()        // Executed on another thread
  {
    y = 1; 
    int b = x;
    ...
  }
}
```

I have questions to the solution two. I can get the point that there could be a third method like this exists. Such a code using the same variables could be hiding in a different library and we may not be aware of it. There is why the author uses `Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide();`

But since `Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide();` is used in one place only, how does the compiler know that it needs to insert another memory barrier in the instructions in Test2 method or even another method that access those fields?

Comment: It forces a memory barrier in every thread that runs in the process.  This kind of crude sledgehammer requires OS support, it pinvokes an OS helper function.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation simply calls the Windows API function [`FlushProcessWriteBuffers()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-flushprocesswritebuffers?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The function generates an interprocessor interrupt (IPI) to all
> processors that are part of the current process affinity.

See [here for more details](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20500)

So to answer your question "since Interlocked.MemoryBarrierProcessWide(); is used in one place only, how does the compiler know that it needs to insert another memory barrier in the instructions in Test2 method":

The compiler doesn't need to do that because the call to `FlushProcessWriteBuffers()` will affect all processors running any code.

Comment: sorry, still confused, what if a thread executes Test2() method first, so it can potentially executes `int b = x;`  first (compiler can reorder instructions in  Test2()  )then b is 0, then a context switch happens, another thread execute  Test2() method normally, so `int a = y;` make y = 0 too, how can `FlushProcessWriteBuffers()` prevent this?